# Angular 4 - How to pass value from parent component to child modules

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to pass the value from parent component to the child module. this is my project structure:

```
++Layout
---admin-layout.component.html
---admin-layout.component.ts
++Dashboard
---dashboard.component.html
---dashboard.component.ts
---dashboard.module.ts
---dashboard.routing.ts
```

and my `app.routing.ts` routing is something like this.

```
export const AppRoutes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component:  AdminLayoutComponent,
  children: [
    {path: '/dashboard', loadChildren: 'PATH/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'},
///
]}];
```

so my question I have a click event in admin-layout.html so how do I send the value from admin layout to dashboard?

currently, I'm sending it via Url something like changing it on the path

```
 {path: '/dashboard/:eventidvalue', loadChildren: 'PATH/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'},
```

when it is routed.

Is there any alternative and clean way of doing it.

Comment: What is this event value, and what is it being used for?

Comment: I will be passing an object

Comment: What is this object, and what is it being used for? You'd better be more collaborative if you want a good answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use a Singleton  service that has one instance, put some date in it and get them everywhere you need.
create a shared module after that create a sharedService and import your that shared modules in your main module and dashboard module

you can use ModuleWithProviders  and forRoot to Provide a singleton service

```
import { SharedService } ...
...
export class SharedModule {
static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
        ngModule: SharedModule,
        providers: [SharedService]
    }
}}
```

and you can import it that way:

```
imports: [
    SharedModule.forRoot(),
],
```

Comment: can I pass an object in this way?